# react router path parameter not working in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Well, I defined the react router as follows:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path="details/:id" element={<ViewNote/>}/>
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and I called it like this in the class component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ViewNote extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
     console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
}
render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h2>{this.props.match.params.id}</h2>
      </div>
     )
 }
}
```

But it shows match undefined in the console!!!

how to solve it??

thanks.

Comment: You're using old react-router code with the latest version. 1. use `element`, not `render` 2. try to only use functional components, class comps are basically deprecated

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: Which version of that does it have class components??

Comment: i use version 6.3.0 of that.